# difference between お世話になっております and お世話になります。

Tags: word-choice

Need a clear explanation about the difference between ***お世話になっております*** and ***お世話になります***。

Answer (score 3):

お世話になります means "I(Someone) will be in your care.". It is the future. For example, 明日からお世話になります。( I will be in your care from tomorrow.)

お世話になっています is present progressive form. It means "I(Someone) am in your care now". お世話になっております is a more polite way of お世話になっています.

Comment: I downvoted but managed to undo it. Downvoted as the sentence as such does not make the distinction of present/future, but undid the downvote considering that [also see the p.s. of my separate answer] if wanting to specifically talk about future, the なっております sounds weird, i.e. in that way there is also an indirect difference in that sense, I guess.

Comment: @Tuomo I don't say お世話になっております is about the future. I say it is present progressive.

Comment: The source of confusion is that there are two dimensions in which both expressions differ. On the one hand, the verb tense (present/present progressive) and on the other hand, the degree of politeness (polite form/humble form). I think you should compare お世話になっています and お世話になっております.

Comment: @ jarmanso7 That's a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

なっております is more formal/polite than なります. Otherwise they can often be used interchangeably (when you want to say "Thank you" in the sense that お世話になります means).

P.S. I downvoted the answer that focused on the present/future, when explicitly wanting to speak about the future, starting with これから continuing with お世話になります sounds natural, but, at least to me, "これからお世話になっております" sounds weird, so in that sense my downvote may not have been justified. I will try to cancel but leave a comment.